# How is the default price of an item in GTM determined?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When I try to sell an item through the Galactic Trade Market, some price is automatically assigned to the item. I can then change the price, but I think many players will keep the default one.

How is this price determined? Is it somehow based on the state of the economy on the server? Or is it a static price (maybe based on the price when selling the item to a vendor)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the default buyout price is 450% of what a vendor will pay.  Deposits vary from 22% of the vendor price (6 hours) to 68% (48 hours).

I have no evidence, but I would not imagine the price would vary.

Comment: Are these numbers based on empirical data, or anecdotal evidence?

Comment: @Mufasa anecdotes are a form of empirical data.

Comment: Sorry, you're correct. http://www.quora.com/Philosophy/Can-anecdotal-evidence-also-be-empirical-evidence I should have asked if it's analytic fact and/or backed with references.

Comment: Based on anecdotal evidence, it seems this is right.

Comment: Also, I think the deposit is based on the actual price, not the default one.