# Is it more profitable to put crafted items onto Auction?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I've now got my crew skills and I am crafting items to level it up. Now that I have access to the Galactic Market, would I be better off putting the items on there than selling them to a merchant?

I think that because they are still low level, starter items, there isn't much point.

Has anyone sold much stuff on the Market yet, or is it still too soon?

Comment: Oof, this is a difficult question for the site. Ingame economies are even more volatile than real world ones. Taking into account supply and demand, the exact costs of what you're crafting (as in how much your purchased components cost), then the quality of what you're selling (beginner/midlevel/endgame), then look at whether or not people are undercutting to the point of no profit after crafting costs and whether or not that's worth it to you, that's subjective. *Plus* the fact that TOR's auction houses are per server (as far as I know), I'm not sure this can escape "too localized."

Comment: From my experience, it *is* more profitable to use the Market. The default price [is 450% of the price you get from vendors](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42647/483) and most of the items I tried to sell at that price did actually sell.

Comment: You forgot that you can reverse engineer the items to receive back some of the materials, which can be used to create new items. Which translates into: more skill increases for the same amount of starting materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience, it is more profitable to use the Market. The default price [is 450% of the price you get from vendors](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42647/483) and most of the items I tried to sell at that price did actually sell.

My character has the Biochem/Bioanalysis combo and I was selling mostly Bioanalysis resources that I had too much, but some crafted Biochem items too (like Hyperneural Resolve System).

Keep in mind that the Market has many disadvantages too: its kiosk can be far away, you don't get the money right away and you have to pay deposit to create the sale (which you get back whether the item sells or the time runs out).

Comment: It's also a good idea to reverse engineer the basic items as then you have a chance to learn the better version of that item.

Comment: Might note that on a successful item sale you do lose a % of the deposit as well. You get part of it back, but you lose a small portion of it. I noticed this last night when the 'sold' mail came in and stated the fact it had taken a bit.

Comment: @JClaspill, that never happened to me. And the mail always says that it includes the deposit, not just part of it.